# If $x$ isn't prime, then there is a prime number $p\mid x$ with $p \leq \sqrt x$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

More specifically, I would like to prove the following:

Let P(a): a is prime

$\forall x \in \mathbb{N^{\geq 2}}, \neg P(x) \Rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{N}, P(y) \land y \hspace{1 pt} |\hspace{1 pt} x \land (y \leq \sqrt{x})$

For this statement to be true, I know that I must show that y is a factor of x. I also know that x can be written in the form $ab$, where a and b are prime numbers (by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic). I think I have the general idea of the direction of this proof, but I can't seem to think of a coherent solution.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Note that if $x=yz$ with $y,z\gt0$ then $y$ or $z\le\sqrt x$, or else $yz>x$

Comment: To me that is almost the definition of being prime, what is your definition?

Comment: Note that "$x$ can be written in the form $ab$, where $a$ and $b$ are prime" is wrong in general. Consider $x=2\cdot 3\cdot 5$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider $A = \{ n \in \mathbb N : 1 < n < a \text{ and } n \mid a \}$. Prove that $A$ is not empty and that its minimal element is prime and less than or equal to $\sqrt a$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ and $b$ are both greater than $\sqrt{x}$ then $ab>\sqrt{x}^2 = x,$ contradiction.  So one of them is less than or equal to $\sqrt{x}$ and it has a prime divisor.

Comment: If I wanted to write a contradiction proof, would I assume that x is true and $\neg (\exists y \in \mathbb{N}, P(y) \land y \hspace{1 pt} |\hspace{1 pt} x \land (y \leq \sqrt{x}))$ is true? I don't really follow your idea.

Comment: The contradiction is only of the fact that $a$ and $b$ can't both be greater than $\sqrt{x}$.  Also $x$ is a number, so it can't be "true" or "false."

Comment: Sorry I meant to write P(x) is true.